# F# literate programming: how to embed plots?

Tags: f#

I've been using `F#` for a few months now and have started looking into ways to create documents and presentations that include static plots/charts with `F#`, much like I was able to do in the programming language `R` with `knitr` and `Beamer` slides.  For literate programming, I've found that [FSharp.Formatting](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting) allows me to export to HTML and that [FSharp.Markdown.Pdf](https://github.com/theburningmonk/FSharp.Markdown.Pdf) will allow me to export to .pdf, but in neither instance is there a clear way to embed plots generated in `F#`.

For creating plots, I'm familiar with [FnuPlot](https://github.com/fsprojects/FnuPlot) (which allows me to write a static plot directly to a .png), [Plotly](https://plot.ly/), and have started looking into [XPlot](https://tahahachana.github.io/XPlot/), but again, there isn't a clear way to include charts from these packages into document produced out of F#.

This may be more of a "plotting in F#" question than literate programming, but is there a simple means of producing a presentation or document with static charts, text/tables, and a custom CSS in `F#`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FsLab journal template lets you turn scripts with Markdown comments and F# code snippets into a nice HTML (and with some limitations into a PDF too). Here is a [sample output that it can produce](http://tpetricek.github.io/Talks/2015/literate-programming/krakow/images/FsLab_Tutorial1.html).

To get started you can:

- Download "FsLab Journal Template" from the [FsLab downloads page](http://fslab.org/download/)
- Get a [Visual Studio Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45373b36-2a4c-4b6a-b427-93c7a8effddb) if you are using VS
- Look at [Literate F# scripts](http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/sidescript.html) and [Embedding output](http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/evaluation.html) documentation.

It supports embedding of XPlot and F# Charting charts out of the box. If you're interested in adding FnuPlot support, then it certainly be done - feel free to [open an issue on GitHub for this](https://github.com/fslaborg/FsLab).